# Running Tasks from different jobs into the same Executor with multiple cores in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible for spark to run **different Tasks** within the **same Executor in the different Cores?** - Consider the following diagram:

```
      Partition-1  Partition-2  Partition-3
           ▲           ▲           ▲
           │           │           │                       ┌─────────────┐
           │           │           │                       │             │
   ┌───────┼───────────┼───────────┼─────┐                 │    Datasource
   │       │           │           │     │                 │             │
   │   ┌───┴────┐ ┌────┴───┐ ┌─────┴───┐ │                 └───┬──────┬──┘
   │   │        │ │        │ │         │ │                     │      │
   │   │ Task-1 │ │ Task-2 │ │  Task-1 │ │                     │      │
   │   │        │ │        │ │         │ │                     │      │
   │   │        │ │        │ │         │ │                Map  │      │ Map
   │   │        │ │        │ │         │ │            Operation-1    Operation-2
   │   │        │ │        │ │         │ │                     │      │
   │   │        │ │        │ │         │ │                     │      │
   │   │        │ │        │ │         │ │         ┌───────────▼┐    ┌▼──────────┐
   │   │        │ │        │ │         │ │         │  Spark     │    │  Spark    │
   │   └────────┘ └────────┘ └─────────┘ │         │  action    │    │   action  │
   │    core-1      core-2      core-3   │         └────────────┘    └───────────┘
   └─────────────────────────────────────┘
                            Spark Executor
```

Consider the fact  that we have the following DAG above - and we run the Spark with **Fair Scheduler instead of FIFO** - so that we have multiple jobs running in parallel.

Comment: Are these parallel or sequential Actions ?

Comment: @thebluephantom - the dag has 2 jobs and they are using "Fair Scheduler" from spark standalone mode - so they might get scheduled in parallel potentially.

Comment: In most cases it is done sequentially. Do you have .par in your code?

Comment: @thebluephantom - the .par does not apply here - as I am referring to the parallel actions - ie 2 actions that may be invoked in parallel - and that does not even need any parallel construct being applied - the Spark may schedule it in parallel.

Comment: Different to what I learned. Ok i give up we do not understand eachother. Success.

Comment: @thebluephantom : all I want to emphasise here with my question is - that by any chance is it a possibility that **spark may schedule the heterogeneous tasks (ie tasks from different jobs)  within the same executor - on the different cores**?

Comment: @thebluephantom - coz such a case may arise if there are 2 competing jobs - that have been scheduled by spark using the Fair Scheduler - as each job will compete for resources - so **will spark allow an executor to harbour tasks from 2 different jobs - or it strictly allows tasks from only one job at a time?**

Comment: I'd also be very interested in proper answer... (.)(.)